# Multiple FireBase listener calls, any exception?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does leaving the listener cause any problem? ie, if I call this code multiple times, does the listener cause multiple threads to be spawned?

```
String ref = Constants.Client + "/" + Constants.firebaseProjects + "/" + Constants.ProjectName + "/units";

DatabaseReference dataBaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ref);
dataBaseRef.keepSynced(true);

dataBaseRef.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot) {

    }       
}
```

Comment: Firebase callbacks are all called on main application thread (with isolated exceptions).  Multiple listeners for same reference are all called for same event - note the 'singleValue' version is just a helper function which automatically does the remove of that instance.

Comment: Also, in theory, rather than creating a new instance of the listener each time use one instance (create it outside of scope) - Firebase supposedly recognizes the same instance (using the 'equals'?) and does not add it again to the same reference.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @Andy If I dont use the same instance is there a chance that it spawns multiple threads?

Comment: Since you asked about threads: the Firebase client uses a single thread for all its network/IO work. It does not spawn a separate thread for each listener. As Any says, your callbacks are invoked on the main thread, so that you can update the UI from them.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Does this dataRef/listener Occupy heap memory? My app is consuming lot of memory, so I doubt whether it is due to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a single event listener the listener will be automatically removed once it's called. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)).

> This listener will be triggered once with the value of the data at the location.

So there won't be any problem to call it multiple times, because it's used only once. Also, as it will be automatically removed it won't spawn multiple threads.

Since you've edited the question for ValueEventListener then the behaviour is different. You'll get various listeners being called when the data on the specified node change. Note that firebase listeners are not lifecycle aware (yet), therefore with many listeners comes many responsabilities of removing them when you don't need them, you might get an exception if the listeners returns a value to an inexistent activity. Or you follow the sugestion of @Andy and use the same listener over and over again.

Comment: Question has been edited, changed from single event listener to valueEventListener